# Mapping Segment of Guest RAM to host file, in PPC QEMU

Tags: qemu, mmap, powerpc

My desire is conceptually simple, I have a file (really a PCIe resource file from /sys/bus/pci/device/.... but that isn't too relevant) on the host that I want to make available somewhere in guest memory, so that changes from either side get reflected to each other.
Since my goal was to actually map a limited segment of PCIe address space in the host, I couldn't productively map the entire guest RAM.
The base command that I am trying to add is listed below.
The goal is to get memory id "bar0.ram" mapped *somewhere* in guest memory.

```
qemu-system-ppc -M ppce500 -cpu e500 -m 64M  -d guest_errors,unimp -bios $PWD/test.elf  -s -object memory-backend-file,size=1m,id=bar0.ram,mem-path=/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:04\:00.0/resource0,share=on  -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:4999,server,nowait -nographic
```

Perhaps this would be easier on ARM or x86, but PPC doesn't offer persistent memory, nvram, multiple memory slots backed by different files, or similar tricks (that I could figure out how to get working).  It does offer ivshmem, but I was unable to figure out how to get that to be transparently mapped into the guest address space.

Vaguely useful/related resources:

- [Mapping guest RAM to file in qemu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616596/mapping-guest-ram-to-file-in-qemu)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1795238/qemu-system-sparc-shared-memory-between-host-and-guest
- https://blog.reds.ch/?p=1379

Answer (score 0):

I have to hope this was absolutely the wrong way to solve the problem that I had, but it worked: I hacked QEMU in stupid ways.

In hw/ppc/e500.c, I created a global variable, and when that variable was set, after the initial register memory, I added another subregion based on whatever was in the global variable.  Yes, you see the address where I stuck the memory hardcoded.

```
@@ -893,6 +893,8 @@ static void ppce500_power_off(void *opaque, int line, int on)
   }
 }

+MemoryRegion *magicbar0 = NULL;
+
 void ppce500_init(MachineState *machine)
 {
     MemoryRegion *address_space_mem = get_system_memory();
@@ -985,6 +987,12 @@ void ppce500_init(MachineState *machine)

     /* Register Memory */
     memory_region_add_subregion(address_space_mem, 0, machine->ram);
+    {
+        if (magicbar0)
+        {
+            memory_region_add_subregion(address_space_mem, 0x8000000, magicbar0);
+        }
+    }

     dev = qdev_new("e500-ccsr");
     object_property_add_child(OBJECT(machine), "e500-ccsr", OBJECT(dev));
```

Also, in softmmu/memory.c, I looked for my magic region name and stored it into the global variable.  Ugly, yes.  I pounded my head against the QOM for far too long before I just gave up and used the global variable.

```
@@ -1618,6 +1618,9 @@ void memory_region_init_ram_from_file(MemoryRegion *mr,
         object_unparent(OBJECT(mr));
         error_propagate(errp, err);
     }
+    extern MemoryRegion *magicbar0;
+    if (!strcmp(name, "bar0.ram"))
+        magicbar0 = mr;
 }

 void memory_region_init_ram_from_fd(MemoryRegion *mr,
```

Things that I did which possibly were unneeded:

- I had the host RAM cover the entire range of memory, including the bar I was trying to map, so that the MMU and friends would play nice.  Fortunately, the second mapping was able to overwrite the first mapping for just that segment.
- I doubled the amount of RAM I allocated--at one point it was only using half of memory.
- I had the guest disable the data cache (I tried anyway)
- This was a bare metal program, so I created an all-RAM TLB cache to let me access address space above the default mapping of only part of RAM.

The command I ran with this included:

```
qemu-system-ppc -M ppce500,memory-backend=foo.ram -cpu e500 -m 256M,slots=2,maxmem=1g  -d guest_errors,unimp -bios $PWD/test.elf  -s -object memory-backend-file,size=256m,id=foo.ram,mem-path=$PWD/realmemory,share=on,prealloc=on -object memory-backend-file,size=1m,id=bar0.ram,mem-path=/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:04\:00.0/resource0,share=on  -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:4999,server,nowait -nographic -S
```

After I did all of that, with the above command `info mtree` showed the desired result:

```
0000000000000000-000000000fffffff (prio 0, ram): foo.ram
0000000008000000-00000000080fffff (prio 0, ram): bar0.ram
```

Even better, mucking with memory at address 0x800_0000 and friends successfully read and wrote a PCIe card behind the host, without the guest having a PCIe driver for that card (or an operating system).

Just to document this (for myself I guess), I used the following assembler in the guest to disable the data cache:

```
#define CONFIG_SYS_HID0_FINAL (HID0_ICE | HID0_ABE | HID0_EMCP)
    lis     r3, CONFIG_SYS_HID0_FINAL@h
    ori     r3, r3, CONFIG_SYS_HID0_FINAL@l
    SYNC
    mtspr   SPRN_HID0, r3
```

And I use the following C in the guest to add a TLB entry (yes, hardcoded ram size):

```
set_tlb(1,
          0x0000000,
          0x0000000,
          MAS3_UR | MAS3_UW | MAS3_UX | MAS3_SR | MAS3_SW | MAS3_SX,
          0,
          0,
          2,
          BOOKE_PAGESZ_256M,
          0);
```

For anyone who has gotten this far, I guess we can all hope that someone will come along and provide an answer that will work with QEMU's APIs, instead of what I ended up doing.